# Scanning using nmap

Tags: dns, nmap

folks.Is there away to use nmap to scan for open resolvers in ones network.I have this command from the nmap page but it seems itsnot working

```
nmap -sU -p 53 --script=dns-recursion <target>
```

Comment: Can you describe "not working"? What do you expect, and what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the command and It is working as spected.

```
[root@Golgota /home/test]# nmap -sU -p 53 --script=dns-recursion 8.8.8.8

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-26 22:39 CET
Nmap scan report for google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)
Host is up (0.021s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/udp open  domain
|_dns-recursion: Recursion appears to be enabled

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.50 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo nmap -sS -sU -PN -p 53 <your_network_subnet>

-sU is UDP scanning
-sS is TCP scanning
-PN dodges host discovery and treats all targets as online.
-p 53 uses port 53 default for DNS

To find your network subnet and netmask, use command ip addr show

1. find your eth0 OR wlan0
2. if for instance you see 192.169.1.100 THEN the range will be 192.169.100.0/24